# How to align the span and html dropdown in same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I designed the UI like the below.

```
<div class="rightbadger">
    <span id="filterRecords">
        Number of Results Per Page
        <%:Html.DropDownList(
            "filterByPageNumber", 
            Model.ResultPerPage,
            null,
            new { onchange = "GetResultsPerPage()" }
        )
        %>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rightbadger { margin-left: 600px;}
```

But span and dropdown list are not aligned properly in same line.in some browsers are looking good but some of the browsers showing like the below.
[image: below is the screen shot of the image]

Comment: <select> inside span? post your css for that div and select

Comment: please let me know clearly.if any sample can you provide

Comment: select element should be seperate one not a inside of span

Comment: I think Sridhar R is right. Also, if it helps, take a look at this question: [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers?rq=1)

Comment: The span should also be a label with a for attribute (with the id of the select). This is makes your page more accessible for blind users, and is the correct html :) .

Answer (score 0):

Just put the CSS

```
.filterRecords select{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align them vertically you probably should put the text into a separate element, like so:

```
<div class="rightbadger">
    <div id="filterRecords">
        <span>Number of Results Per Page</span>
        <%:Html.DropDownList(
            "filterByPageNumber", 
            Model.ResultPerPage,
            null,
            new { onchange = "GetResultsPerPage()" }
        )
        %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then vertical align the 2 element as you want them to be:

```
#filterRecords span,
#filterRecords select{ /*or just '#filterRecords *' */
    vertical-align: bottom; /*or middle; or top; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to set for span and dropdown:

```
float:left;
width:300px;
display:block;
```