# Crossbrowser input text vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to create input that will have the same rendering in Chrome, FF, IE8-11.

I usually don't add height property for text inputs and i use padding-top/bottom + line-height;

I think that should work, but in my IE input text a bit lower than it has to be.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/FNMZS/1

HTML

```
<div id="all">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#all {
    padding:100px;
}
input {
    border:1px solid #000;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1em;
    padding:4px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE so I couldn't observe your case however since your code seems also OK to me I thought that may the scope of your reset part should be higher.

Please refer to Meyer's or HTML5 Doctor's reset CSS. I use an modified version of [HTML5 Doctor's reset css](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/).

Two url below can also useful for you at least in future.

[styling texty inputs only](http://css-tricks.com/styling-texty-inputs-only/)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers.)

Also please be sure that your observation is *true*. Once, I was also in a same thought for a text positioning but after taking screenshot, and analyzing in photoshop I understood that it was just a prejeduce against IE. There were no difference between the browsers.

I hope these helps.