# I Need To Shift Only Name Of CheckBox To Some Pixels top not the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I have created a checkbox with name.I am getting name of checkbox lower than the checkbox.
so i need to make those in parallel(stright).

```
checkbox c=new checkbox("name");
  c.setStyleName("checkbox_style");
```

> Below one is checkbox css code

```
.checkbox_styleinput { 
    font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold", "Segoe UI Semibold IE";
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

> By using above code the entire checkbox and its name is shifting up But
>   I need to shift name of checkbox to upper to make checkbox and name of checkbox parallel.

Please help me to complete this

Comment: can you give more information.. or a dummy link so i can get idea

Comment: provide your html being generated.

Comment: yes i need to see what HTML code comes than i can help you

Comment: I have Added css style once see at that and help me to resolve this problem                                                                 thanq

Answer (score 0):

Known behavior. You can see it also in the showcase.

Fix by adding the following in your stylesheet. It will be applied to all `checkbox` input types.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can apply the same also for `radio` inputs.

Comment: This won't work. See different solutions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers Scroll to the most popular solution (close to the bottom).

Comment: Thanq Its Working Successfully.Instead Of Vertical-align: middle I used Vertical-align: -2px.           Thanks a lot for giving me solution

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to solve this problem, and make checkboxes look consistent across all browsers:

```
.gwt-CheckBox {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    text-indent: -26px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    *overflow: hidden;
    width: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I got the solution.....I used below code Try it,Instead of -2px you can use your own length

```
.checkbox_styleinput {
```

vertical-align : -2px;
}

> thanq