# How to align input fields?

Tags: html, css

I have two table rows with Date and Time values. My input fields are not centered, I aligned my tr to left. So I'm trying to center input from first tr and second tr.

Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/qyq9cp7j/

HTML code:

```
<tr align="left">
   <td class="dateTime">
      <label>Pick up Date</label>
      <input name="DateFrom" id="DateFrom" style="width:100px" size="10" maxlength="10" class="dtefld" value="">
      <label>Pick up Time</label>
      <input name="TimeFrom" id="TimeFrom" class="time" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
   </td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr align="left">
  <td class="dateTime">
     <label>Drop off Date</label>
     <input name="DateTo" id="DateTo" style="width:100px" size="10" maxlength="10" class="dtefld" value="">
     <label>Drop off Time</label>
     <input name="TimeTo" id="TimeTo" class="time" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
   </td>
</tr>
```

If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

Comment: @ryan That's not a duplicate.

Comment: Is not duplicate @ryan.

Comment: Can anyone vote for this question because is marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
label {display: inline-block; width: 100px;}
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: @GCyrillus Forgot to add bro! `:P`

Comment: This fixed the problem. Can you explain why I have to use display:inline-block and width:100px?

Comment: @user3023588 `inline-block` gives you a `block` element features like `width`, `height`, `padding` and `margin` and also, it doesn't take the full width like `block` level elements and behaves in consistent with `inline` elements. They are flowing elements with the characters of `block`.

Comment: That make sense. Thank you!