# How to align checkboxes labels

Tags: html, css

The labels of checkboxes are not properly aligned? IMG 1 labels are properly aligned but not for IMG 2.How to align them?

Properly aligned text label of checkbox

[image]

misaligned label of checkbox

[image]

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Can you provide HTML and CSS code please ?

Comment: The code can't be shared but could you please mention some CSS tricks or HTML tricks to resolve this issue. Already tried white-space still no luck.

Comment: You should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you and not make the work for you

Comment: why can't you share the code? *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."* https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use table

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="text">Some Long Texttttttttttt</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.text{
   width:100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td class="text">Some Long Texttttttttttt</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css

```
display:inline-block
```

for both checkbox and text,Make sure that you include them with in a common div for those checkbox and text.

Comment: Hi Rajmal, I tried display function but inline-block was not helping. However, inline-flex was making it aligned but making the text font and checkbox size small