# How to put a label to right of a checkbox in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying lots of ways to put a                                             `<input type="checkbox" id="123"/>`
infront of a label, but they're leaving a huge gap between theirselves.
Any workaround? Here's my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input type="checkbox" id="ProcessingConsultantYN" value="0" />
            <label class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" aria-describedby="ProcessingConsultantYN" id="lbProcessingConsultant" for="ProcessingConsultantYN">Обработва се от Кредитен Консултант</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's how it looks when being displayed on the website and what I actually want to fix:
[image]

Comment: Based from the classes used, you are using Bootstrap?

Comment: You can better look for that solution when you go through bootstrap examples and documentation. [Bootstrap Form Element](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: Yes, twitter bootstrap. I can't find anything wrong in the html inspector also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below Code Just replace your `label` tag class with `checkbox-inline`.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <input type="checkbox" id="ProcessingConsultantYN" value="0" />
      <label class="checkbox-inline" aria-describedby="ProcessingConsultantYN" id="lbProcessingConsultant" for="ProcessingConsultantYN">Обработва се от Кредитен Консултант</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you edited my answer what so wrong in that? @Swellar

Comment: I put your codes in the built-in snippet instead of `JSFiddle`

Comment: But both codes are same and JSFiddle or Code Snippet will be not a proper issue for editing my answer. @Swellar

Comment: It actually worked, my bad. Adding input-group-addon messes it up again.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code. under the label, tag use your checkbox tag as per [BOOTSTRAP official](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) doc, or you can modify the structure what ever you want.

I just simply try to make an option with form-control you can use `.form-control-static` class as per [Static control](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static)

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label> <input type="checkbox"> Обработва се от Кредитен Консултант </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><input type="checkbox" id="ProcessingConsultantYN" value="0" /></span>
          <label class="form-control">Обработва се от Кредитен Консултант</label>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

```
label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}
input {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  *overflow: hidden;
}
```

AS @dfsq said check if something wrong or not in HTML inspector.
Check the above link if it works or not.This link should sure help you.
check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8EGn/12249/)

Answer (score 0):

class `pull-left` should suffice for you.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <input type="checkbox" id="ProcessingConsultantYN" value="0" />
      <label class="pull-left" aria-describedby="ProcessingConsultantYN" id="lbProcessingConsultant" for="ProcessingConsultantYN">Обработва се от Кредитен Консултант</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pulling it left makes it go over the actual checkbox.