# CSS - how to make the checkbox and label in one line?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How to put the checkbox and label in one line?
[image]

```
<style>
          @supports (zoom:2) {
            input[type=checkbox]{
            zoom: 2;
            }
          }
          @supports not (zoom:2) {
            input[type=checkbox]{
              transform: scale(2);
              margin: 15px;
            }
          }
          label{
            /* fix vertical align issues */
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-top: 10px;
            color:black;
          }
        </style>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="check_gdpr" id="check_gdpr" checked /> 
        <label for="cc">Inform me by e-mail</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the input in the label:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check_gdpr" id="check_gdpr" checked>Inform me by e-mail</label>
```

Comment: Remove the CSS for both your checkbox and your label and see if they line up. If they do, just add the CSS that's necessary for aesthetics and not alignment.

Answer (score 1):

just put your checkbox and label in span

example`<span class="get-inline"><lable>Inform me by e-mail</lable></span>
<span class="get-inline"><input  type="checkbox" name="check_gdpr" id="check_gdpr" checked /> </span>`

now add css like this:

```
.get-inline{display:inline-block;}
```

i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
vertical-align: top
```

to

```
vertical-align: middle
```

in your CSS for label and it should work just fine.

Comment: I am sorry to learn that it did not work for you. I am sharing a link of the solution for a query similar to yours. Hope it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/306593/9628414

Comment: Tried that link but still does not work, the checkbox is not in the same line of text.