# Aligning labels and inputs

Tags: html, css

Hey how can I align inputs with labels in css, that the input boxes are aligned right and the labels left? I somehow don't get it. I already aligned the labels with `flex:left;` but it does not work for me for the inputs. 
Here is what I got so far:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

[Quick solve] You can just put a fixed width to elements, maybe `width: 50%;` to inputs and `width: 50%;` to labels too. Or something like 70%-30%. It's your choice..