# Align radio buttons vertically, when they are on the right side of the label?

Tags: html, css

How can I align the radio buttons? I would like them to be lined up on top of each other.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74ymp9wo/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">

</form>
```

Comment: radio buttons are already aligned vertically, how are you expecting ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align checkboxes and their labels consistently cross-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers)

Comment: is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/dickensas/vq25co4y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

**Method 1:**

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Radio Buttons</h2>

<form>
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

**Method 2:**

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Radio Buttons</h2>

<form>
  <div>
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  </div>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```