# Is there a way to set (inherit) background color of an unchecked checkbox with CSS? (without rebuilding it with a pseudoelement) Custom color scheme?

Tags: html, css

A problem: I'd like to use a custom background color; unchecked checkboxes are "white" in this case. Here's the shortest illustration:

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

A screenshot, just in case:

[image]

Now, I know that a basic approach would be [to create a custom checkbox pseudoelement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56558431/3995261), but I still wonder if there's a "low-code" solution.

I also know that one can use `accent-color` to style the "checked" state and `color-scheme: dark;` for dark mode (see more detail [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/09/simplifying-form-styles-accent-color/), for instance: they even say that browser ensures accessibility when using `accent-color` by ensuring sufficient color contrast).

So, is there a way to set the background color of an unchecked checkbox without rebuilding it with a pseudoelement? (At least to inherit the main background color.) Looks like there's no way to create a custom `color-scheme` (yet), but may be I've overlooked some other way?

Comment: _"So, is there a way to set the background color of an unchecked checkbox without rebuilding it with a pseudoelement?"_  in short, **no**, because HTML input elements were historically (and generally still are today) ["_replaced elements_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), specifically OS-native widgets (though nowadays, most browsers bring their own widgets) which were completely opaque to JS+DOM and CSS. Other than the (very recently added) `accent-color` property (and assuming your visitors' browsers all support it) there's not much else you can do.